# Executing a callout at the end of a chain of methods operating in @future context

Tags: apex, callout, future, asynchronous, queueable-apex

I have a callout method that is executed as the last step of a long chain of methods when a record's status get changed to "completed". Early in this sequence, we have a method that we have decided needs to be @future in order to help us manage governor limit constraints. Much further down we have a DML statement that inserts a record, and then a trigger is fired as a result. That trigger has within it a callout that is also a @future method. I know @future methods cannot be called from a future context, so I'm trying to figure out a way to accomodate this.

My first thought was to try switching from future methods to queueable apex, which provides the luxury of chaining queueable methods together. However, the future method with the callout is only happening as a consequence of the record insert firing the trigger--which is to say that there is a lot of stuff that needs to happen synchronously after the first Future method, but before the second Future method with the callout.

I'm wondering if anyone has any elegant solutions (or any solutions at all) for this kind of sequencing issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BzEP.png)
[image]

Comment: If timing isn't that much of an issue, can you schedule the DML operation?

Comment: an async transaction is an async transaction. When it executes is up to SFDC so you can't depend on when it executes. I don't see why queueable is an issue for you.

Comment: @cropredy it's totally acceptable to call System.enqueueJob(newCallout) while in future execution context, right? If so, turning the class that contains my callout method into a class that implements queueable might be my solution.

Comment: personally, I'd use queueable for both 1st and 2nd